# Custom delegate method usage

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to use custom delegate between NSObject (MenuComponent) and UIViewController(fullVC) class. Delegate is declared in UIViewController, because UIViewController need to send data (title and url) to my NSObject class.

My protocol methods is in UIViewController(FullVC)

FullVC.h file

```
@class FullVC;
@protocol MenuComponentDelegate <NSObject>   

-(void)shareToView:(NSString *)titleString inUrl:(NSString *)urlString;

@end 
@interface       FullVC:UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate,UITextViewDelegate> 
@property (nonatomic,assign) id delegate;

@end
```

I am trying to call the delegate method in My FullVC. m File by

FullVC.m

```
@interface FullVC () 

@end
@implementation FullVC

 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
     [super viewDidLoad];
 }

 -(void)scrollViewInit
 {  
    _title= @“Title of a Link”;

    _urlString = @“Link of the Url”;

        if ([delegate     respondsToSelector:@selector(sharetoView:inUrl:)])

         {

                NSLog(@“Checking urlString in scrollView method: %@", _urlString);

                 [self.delegate shareToView:_title inUrl:_urlString];

             }

      }
```

My shareToView Method is implemented in my NSObject Class

MenuComponent.m

```
 @interface MenuComponent() <MenuComponentDelegate>

 @property (nonatomic, weak) NSString *titleToShare;
 @property (nonatomic, weak) NSString *urlToShare;

 @end 

@implementation MenuComponent

      -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {

       if ([self.nav_controller.topViewController isKindOfClass:[FullVC class]])
        {
             if (indexPath.row==0)
             {
                  [(FullVC *)self.vav_controller.topViewController setDelegate:self];
           NSLog(@“The value of title to share: %@“,titleToShare);

              }
          }

      }
  -(void)shareToView:(NSString *)titleString inUrl:(NSString *)urlString
     {
         NSLog(@"title string after passing is: %@", titleString);
         NSLog(@"url string after passing is: %@", urlString);
     }
        @end
```

I am having problem to delegate the data. My shareToView method seems out of scope. My NSLogs are not Printing. The only NSLog printing is the one that is showing value for titleToShare. But the value is printing as Null.

The value of title to share:(null)

Could some one help me how to call delegate method since it looks like controller is not calling and not sure it is in scope? Thank you

Comment: put some breakpoints in your methods, learn to use the debugger...

Comment: I did use debugger and it is not going into the method to call. So I believe the delegate method is not in scope and not sure how I can make it to recognize. The method seems to have never called. Thanks for the help.